# How can I expose an embedded PowerShell runspace to remoting

Tags: .net, powershell, embed, powershell-remoting, runspace

I have an ASP.Net application which can run embedded runspaces for which I have built a fairly extensive PowerShell functionality including:

- Interactive console, and Web base ISE-like UI
- a number of commandlets exposing the app functionality & management
- a PS drive provider to browse the app content... etc.

The trouble is that I need that functionality to be accessible by Windows PowerShell Console to be available to build scripts or configuration scripts etc., so I would need to expose such an embedded runspace externally via PowerShell remoting. I know of the existence of PowerShellTunnel and the remoting verver that preceeded this but those solutions are limited. I would need to expose the full functionality of such runspace to the external scripts e.g. in interactive mode, I have the Web/in-app interactivity sorted. But to have the full story I need the remoting part.

Has anyone done this and could you point me in a direction where I can find how can I enable remote (or even local) Windows Powershell console to be able to create a proper connection to my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using an Http channel like Scott Hanselman wrote about some time ago?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScriptBlockAndRunspaceRemotingInPowerShell.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be solving the problem of interactivity. It looks similar to what can be solved with  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellTunnel/. http://powershellremoting.codeplex.com/ is also interesting.

Overall breaking out of the confines of the web-app seems a bit tough.

Comment: Accepting the answer as I believe there isn't a better way for now and the fact that Hanselman is struggling with it helped me realise it :)